# iPhone search function

Tags: ios, applications

Is it possible to get the search function of iPhone (when you go at the first screen on left) to work as the spotlight works when you put in words and display a dictionary ?

If not , is the same dictionary app which is installed on OSX, available for iOS? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone spotlight doesn't have the dictionary function built in.

The dictionary app isn't available for iOS as well. But you can try this [free app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dictionary.com-dictionary/id308750436?mt=8) from Dictionary.com. I use this a lot and find it quite useful.

Comment: ye got it. Too many buttons around for a dict bit annoying. guess i can live with that tho

Comment: For some application, like Safari, or even Stanza, you can actually press and hold the word, there will be a Define pop up. Select it, and iOS will give you the definition of the word.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a jailbroken iPhone, the free tweak SpotDict adds a button to the Spotlight interface for access to looking up words in the built-in dictionary. [Here's a review of it with screenshots.](http://modmyi.com/content/7618-review-spotdict-access-ios-dictionary-spotlight.html)